# Origine étymologique de « la laye » d'une motoneige ?

Tags: étymologie, québec

Au Québec, on parle de « la laye du sled ». Autrement dit, « la chenille de la motoneige ». D'où vient ce mot ?

Comment: On entend l'i-grec, ça rime avec cobaye.

Comment: Merci pour la précision ! Vous avez ajouté _sled_, et donc il se peut que la _laye_ soit aussi un emprunt à l'anglais ? Je peux pas dire si _the lie of the sled_ fait référence à quoi que ce soit en anglais mais il y a une connexion entre _lie_ et _lay_ qui dans certains cas peuvent peut-être être équivalents dans le sens d'_arrangement_ ou de _disposition_ ; j'ai vu qu'on dit _tracks_ en anglais pour chenille sur certains sites etc. Sur Kijiji l'emploi de _laye_ pour décrire le type de chenille est bien fréquent !

Comment: Je ne crois pas que ce soit un emprunt de l'anglais. Et oui, c'est toujours des « tracks ».

Answer (score 1):

Potentiellement cela vient du verbe [layer](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/layer)

C'est la première idée qui m'est venue en voyant le terme associé  à une moto neige dans cette question.

J'imagine que la moto neige pouvant servir à passer dans un endroit difficilement praticable autrement cela a été dérivé "d'ouvrir une laie" tel qu'utilisé dans [des codes forestiers du 19 ème](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-zdEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA417&lpg=PA417&dq=ouvrir+une+laie&source=bl&ots=s57l219LbI&sig=JbdcJy5XclB1mbT6DlU54sb95Ss&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCmau6sInXAhXQSxoKHWgsBeUQ6AEIQTAG#v=onepage&q=ouvrir%20une%20laie&f=false)

Je *suppose* que le terme fait référence aux sentiers que les sangliers tracent dans les forets, mais je ne saurais pas assurer que le lien avec la laie, femelle du sanglier, en est vraiment la cause.

Comment: Ce pourrait aussi peut-être être une déformation de _laize_, la chenille étant techniquement une bande entre deux lisières. Je ne sais pas. Il faut davantage de recherche et/ou d'informations. Parfois, [ceci](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) peut être utile. Merci !

Comment: @Galèrefranquiste ça a du sens également, probablement plus. Je ne sais pas pourquoi ma première idée est allée vers la forêt, probablement à cause de l'image de grand espaces quand je pense canada et moto-neige :)

Comment: Il se trouve également, dans le Dictionnaire de l'Académie françoise Tome Second, Paris MDCCXL (1760) « Une route coupée dans une forêt, dans une futaie. _Tracer une laye, faire une laye dans une forêt_. ». Rien a voir avec le forêt de Saint-Germain en Laye, par contre.

Comment: @JohnCornellier j'en viens à me demander si St Germain en laye n'a pas été fondée dans une clairière du coup :)